# Why to choose System.Threading over BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Why would I decide to choose working directly with System.Threading over BackgroundWorker if the last one abstracts for me the treading managemnet?

I can't see cases where I couldn't use BackgroundWorker to replace System.Threading

Comment: Well its a typical case of convenience vs control/granularity. You may want to look at System.Threading.Task, it is a replacement for backgroundWorker in newer version of .NET

Comment: replacement for backgroundWorker  officially speaking?? thank I will take a look

Comment: Tasks are not a "replacement" for `BackgroundWorker`, they apply to some of the same things; but they're equally useful on their own merits and have specific benefits over each other.

Comment: With TAP, I [don't see a use for BGW anymore](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/thread-is-dead.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` has been around since .NET 2.0 and was intended to aid in writing code that will run in a background thread and not bog down the UI thread.  It originally appeared with Windows Forms, but also works with WPF or any future UI framework that registers a synchronization context.  It allows you to report progress and results back to the UI thread without having to deal with `InvokeRequired`/`BeginInvoke` as well supports cancellation.

The Task Parallel Library (TPL) was introduced in .NET 4 and is intended to model asynchronous tasks.  These tasks are asynchronous and may or may not be run on another thread.  Examples of something that doesn't run on another thread is asynchronous IO and tasks that need to run on the UI (while still being asynchronous).  This task metaphor also supports futures (or continuations) so that you can chain tasks together with `ContinueWith`, sometimes using specific synchronization contexts so that you can do things like run a task on a UI thread (to update the UI, for example).

Tasks also support cancellation and multiple tasks can share a cancellation token so a requested cancellation cancels multiple tasks.

One of the differences is a `Task` doesn't have an inherent method of reporting progress back to the UI.  Of course it's possible, but it's not built into the interfaces.  `Task`s also support cancellation.

If you only have one thing you want to do in the background and you specifically want to communicate back to a UI like report progress, I would recommend `BackgroundWorker`.  Otherwise I generally recommend using `Task<T>` (or `Task` if no result is necessary).  `Task` is inherently used in the C# 5 async/await syntax...

Comment: thanks for your big reply, I didn't know about Task from 4.0 before my question was posted. Would you have to know, asynchronous speaking, what I wouldn't do with BackgroundWorker that I would with Task ?

Comment: As I detailed in my answer, a background worker models one unit of work that you want to run on a threadpool thread. (it also models "units of work" like progress and completion).  Tasks model individual asynchronous tasks.  Tasks dependencies can then be invoked with things like ContinueWith, WaitAny, WaitAll, etc.  So you can have multiple units of work.  BackgroundWorker, although making reporting progress to a UI thread easier, is difficult to model multiple units of work--which Tasks would be better at.

Comment: The question is System.Threading over BackgroundWorker.  Not Task over BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Blam Yes, and `Tasks` is in `System.Threading` (`Task<T>`, `Task`, etc) are in `System.Threading`.  Use of `Thread` is pretty much deprecated...

Answer (score 3):

I hope you attempt to think about the intention of each approaches.

BackgroundWorker was designed for Windows Forms mainly at the very beginning (though it can be used in WPF as well), and it only offers some functionality of asynchronous operation. Compared it to all classes under System.Threading, you can see BackgroundWorker obviously is built upon them.

With all classes under System.Threading, you can build your own BackgroundWorker and enjoy more functionality and control over your code. The difficulty here is sharp learning curve, and debugging challenges.

So if you think BackgroundWorker is enough, keep using it. If you find something missing, building blocks in System.Threading can be your helpers.

In .NET Framework 4, Microsoft designs another set of classes upon System.Threading, named Task-based Asynchronous Pattern,

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957

Using it, you can almost forget about BackgroundWorker, as it offers much more functionality and give you enough control, while does not require you to dive into the complexity of working with System.Threading directly.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I understand the popular way of using BackgroundWorker to avoid freezing the UI. But it can be used with windows services as well for example. Besides the thread priority I don't see choose BackgroundWorker over System.Threading. I will take a look on your link

Comment: I seriously doubt BackgroundWorker progress reporting can be used effectively in a Windows Service--if that is indeed a requirement.  I'd also question whether the Complete event would be invoked correctly.

Comment: BGW works in a Win32 service the same way it works in a Console app: all its events are invoked via the thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [blog post on the subject](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html).

In short, you should use `async Task`s if you possibly can. `Thread` does provide some additional "knobs" - such as `Priority` - but usually those knobs are not necessary, and programmers often turn them the wrong way anyway.

Comment: There still is an issue with longevity that the LongRunning option doesn't cover. I think your answer is OK for client apps, not so clear for servers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: What issue? I use TAP on the server side all the time.

Answer (score 0):

For one you cannot set scheduling priority on BackgroundWorker but you can on a Thread.

[Thread.Priority Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx)

Comments that question my answer continue to refer to Task and ThreadPool.  The stated question is not about Task nor ThreadPool and neither is my answer.

Please refer to the code sample from the link above.  It clearly demonstrates assigning priority prior to starting the thread and control over starting the thread.

Complete code sample:

```
PriorityTest priorityTest = new PriorityTest();
ThreadStart startDelegate =  new ThreadStart(priorityTest.ThreadMethod);

Thread threadOne = new Thread(startDelegate);
threadOne.Name = "ThreadOne";
Thread threadTwo = new Thread(startDelegate);
threadTwo.Name = "ThreadTwo";

threadTwo.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
threadOne.Start();
threadTwo.Start();

// Allow counting for 10 seconds.
Thread.Sleep(10000);
priorityTest.LoopSwitch = false;
```

I tested this and ThreadTwo starts and finishes on ThreadPriority.BelowNormal.  In my test threadOne processes about 10X as threadTwo.

BackGroundWorker has no Priority property.  A BackgroundWorker starts with the default priority of Normal.  BackgroundWorker thread priority can be changed in DoWork but changing the priority of a thread once the work has started is clearly not the same.

Comment: make sense, would you see other scenario?

Comment: What task priority are you talking about?

Comment: he is talking about thread priority, BackgroundWorker is always high priority

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the priority of thread pool threads.  The default task scheduler uses thread pool threads for tasks that aren't related to asynchronous IO (or a particular synchronization context).  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/harip/archive/2010/10/11/threadpool-work-item-priority.aspx

Comment: And actually, if you *can* change the priority on `BackgroundWorker` you can also change the priority on a `Task`.  It's just not a good idea to do either.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Please show how to change the thread priority on a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Within the `DoWork` event handler call `Thread.CurrentThread.Priority=ThreadPriority.Lowest`  The link I posted earlier explains why this is a bad idea.  What method do you use to change the priority of a single task?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes Thread has a Priority property and BackgroundWorker does not.  According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx.  Gets or sets a value indicating the scheduling priority of a thread.  The Background worker would still be scheduled as Highest.

Comment: @blam okay, they how do you change the priority of a task then?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I don't know how to change the priority on an individual task or if it can be done and that was not the question.  As stated prior I mistyped Task when I meant Thread.  Sorry and thanks for correcting me.  Truce? I gave your answer a +1.

Comment: @Blam I detailed that you do it the same way as `BackgroundWorker` by using `Thread.Priority` within the `Task` delegate.  But, neither are recommended.  So, your answer does not make sense.  I.e. if you can change the priority of a `Thread` you *can* change the priority of a `BackgroundWorker` (and `Task`)

Comment: @PeterRitchie  No it is not the same as I have already explained.  A  BackGroundWorker getting assigned priority of Highest, scheduled, and then changing its priority once it is called it not the same.  A Thread which can assign its priority PROIR to to being started.  Stating at a low Highest priority then changing to Lowest is not the same starting as Lowest.  Why do you keep coming back to Task when the question is Threading (not task) over BackGroundWorker?

Comment: @Blam  Both tasks (your original answer) and `BackgroundWorker` use thread pool threads.  You cannot change the priority of a threadpool thread *prior to being started* because you have no control on its start (or its creation/reuse, which is the problem).  But, you can still technically *set* it's priority while it's running.

Comment: @PeterRitchie For the 3rd time my answer is not about Task and neither is the stated question.  As for your assertion cannot change the priority of a thread prior to being started and no control when it is started please refer to the code sample I added to my answer.  It is from the link that has been in my answer for some time.

Comment: "A BackgroundWorker starts with a priority of Highest". The default priority of the `BackgroundWorker` thread is `ThreadPriority.Normal`, *not* `ThreadPriority.Highest`.  Simply putting `Trace.WriteLine(Thread.Current.Priority);` at the start of the `DoWork` handler will show you that.